# Trying to get the name of charity organisations with their locations-SPARQL

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am trying to create a SPARQL query which gets the charity organisations and their location from DBpedia.

Here is the link to one charity -- http://dbpedia.org/page/Stonewall_(charity).

I am trying to get all the charities that exist with the names and location.

I want to retrieve `dbp:name` along with `dbo:headquarter`.

Comment: What have you tried?  This is not a complex query... once you decide how an organization is qualified as a "charity."

Comment: @salman12 This is not a platform for letting other people doing your homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
select distinct ?name (group_concat(?headquarter;separator=",")) where 

{?s a dbo:Organisation.
?s dbo:status "Charity".
?s dbp:name ?name.
?s  dbo:headquarter/rdfs:label ?headquarter } 

LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Hi can you show me how to convert this to javascript form as I want to implement it on a html page.

Comment: @salman12 And now your colleague asked the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41786067/expected-error-in-sparql-query-javascript-error