# How to display Charities in UK - SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, dbpedia

I am trying to display all the charities in the UK but it does not show up, Here is the link I am using from DBPEDIA - http://dbpedia.org/page/Category:Charities_based_in_the_United_Kingdom

Here is the SPARQL query produced :

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX type: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dct: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX dbc: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category>


SELECT *
WHERE {
  ?Charities dct:subject dbc:Charities_based_in_the_United_Kingdom.
  }
Limit 5
].join(" ");
```

Right now it just shows the variable `?Charities` how can I display the list of charities too? thanks for your time:)

Comment: We are not here to do your homework.  [Trying to get the name of charity organisations with their locations-SPARQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41774220/trying-to-get-the-name-of-charity-organisations-with-their-locations-sparql)

Comment: Also see [Expected bracket error in SPARQL query, javascript error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41786067/expected-error-in-sparql-query-javascript-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick (worked for me) :

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>        
PREFIX type: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
## Added ##
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT ?actor WHERE { 
 ?actor <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Charities_based_in_the_United_Kingdom>
}
```

Comment: What is the difference to the original query? Both return the same results

Answer (score 0):

The error in your query is the definition of the `dbc` prefix.

Your definition `PREFIX dbc: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category>` results in the URI `http://dbpedia.org/resource/CategoryCharities_based_in_the_United_Kingdom`, which is missing a colon.

The correct prefix is:

```
PREFIX dbc: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>
```

With this change, your code works for me.